# Does compiler detect false shared variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

As i prepared some code sample for a small presentation of OpenMP to my teammate i found a weird case. First i wrote a classic loop :

```
void sequential(int *a, int size, int *b)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i] * i;
    }
}
```

A correct OpenMP usage of a for directive is simple. We just have to move `int i` declaration in for scope to make it `private`.

```
void parallel_for(int *a, int size, int *b)
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i] * i;
    }
}
```

But when i wrote the following function, I expected i get a different result of the 2 other due to the shared `int j`I declared out-of the for loop scope. But using my test framework I don't see the error I expected, an incorrect value at the output of that function.

```
void parallel_for_with_an_usage_error(int *a, int size, int *b)
{
    int j;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        /*int*/ j = a[i]; //To be correct j should be declared here, in-loop to be private !
        j *= i;
        b[i] = j;
    }
}
```

I have a complete source code for testing, it build with VS'12 and gcc (with C++11 enable) here http://pastebin.com/NJ4L0cbV

Have you an idea of what's the compiler do ? Does it detect the false sharing, does in move `int j` in the loop due to an optimization heuristic ?

Thank

Comment: I would guess that `j` is enregistered and doesn't actually correspond to memory in the generated program, since it would not be observable in a data-race-free program.

Comment: What if you change the declaration to `volatile int j;` and set it once after the loop? That should prevent the compiler from messing with the scope of the declaration.

Comment: No, but a cache profiler might (valgrind/cachegrind)

Comment: When you have race conditions like this, anything can happen - under some conditions, unfortunately, even the correct answer.  That's one of the things that make race conditions so dangerous - they can lurk undetected for some time, and then you increase "size" or change compiler options or something, and code previously thought of as good breaks.  What's going on here is hard to guess; you can look at the assembly and see if j is removed (it's not needed anywhere else; try printing j at the end), or if you're just being lucky with timing/interleaving, or...

Comment: Thank you for your help and good remark, I finally find a way to demonstrate the error. I use a cout in the loop to dump the thread id and j. But I will lead more investigation to double-check what the compiler does!

Comment: @alexbuisson: Take care: `std::cout` are not thread-safe!

Comment: @alexbuisson, if you put the cout/printf in a critical block you can see the output.  I tried `printf("i %d, j %d, b[i] %d, thread id %d\n", i, j, b[i], omp_get_thread_num());`.  This shows that j has a race condition but that b[i] is okay.  It's as if the compiler converts it to `b[i] = a[i] * i` and removes `j`.  Setting j volatile did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion what might be happening is that compiler is doing some optimization. Since in the above pasted code (without cout), the variable j is not being anywhere other than inside the loop, the compiler can put the declaration of j inside the loop in the produced assembly code.

Another possibility is that the compiler might be converting the 3 statements inside the loop into one single statement, i.e. from

```
/*int*/ j = a[i]; //To be correct j should be declared here, in-loop to be private !
j *= i;
b[i] = j;
```

to,

```
b[i] = a[i] * i;
```

Compiler will do this optimization regardless of whether its an OpenMP code or not.